# How to append jquery script after a body tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I needed to put my script after the body tag to make sure that my script runs after all the elements are loaded. I would greatly appreciate your help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(document.body).prepend(
        console.log('test8'); 

        //custom jquery
        if ($('div.fc-bg table').length > 0) {     
            var holiday = ['2016-12-01','2016-12-23','2016-12-30'];
            $.each(holiday, function(i, val) {
                var date = val; //'2016-12-01';
                $('.fc-day-top[data-date='+date+']').addClass('holiday');        
            });     
        } //end of custom jQuery  
    )};
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: For that you must have to show your code

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(document.body).prepend(
        console.log('test8'); 
        
        //custom jquery
        if($('div.fc-bg table').length > 0 ){     

             var holiday = ['2016-12-01','2016-12-23','2016-12-30'];
                $.each(holiday, function(i, val){
                    var date = val; //'2016-12-01';
                     $('.fc-day-top[data-date='+date+']').addClass('holiday');        

                });     

        } //end of custom jquery  
    )};
    
});

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai i added the script above

Comment: @bharat patidar i added the script above

Comment: @mmahinay why do you need to append js with js on a page??

Comment: Your code already runs when the elements have been loaded due to your use of a `document.ready` handler. All you need to do to make your code work is to remove the `$(document.body).prepend(` block, as that's completely invalid.

Comment: hi @madalinivascu it seems that my script runs before the widget fullcalendar gets loaded in my webpage

Comment: @mmahinay  can you provide the code for that widget fullcalendar?

Comment: hi @madalinivascu i have it in my codepen account http://codepen.io/mmahinay/pen/bBvdzw   and now i'm integrating it in OutSystems platform..and I'm trying to get around putting the script at the end of the body tag :)

Comment: Putting your script inside or outside the body tag won't make any difference.  Your widget script has *loaded*, but not yet initialised - you need to hook into the initialisation of the widget, not of the document.

Comment: thank you @RoryMcCrossan it indeed prints out 'test8'...but the code below it doesn't seem to work when in fact 'div.fc-bg table' exist on the page...is it because my code loads before the page loads the table?

Comment: @mmahinay see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use $(document).ready() event for purposes like this. And no need to append a script after body tag. You can put is anywhere in body element. For more info see documentation here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: hi @maksymvoronytskyi in my code above i removed the .prepend and use the .ready() as per your suggestion...why is it that it prints out 'test8' but doesn't get the class as for the second statements of code? when the webpage have a div.fc-bg table in it

Comment: can you provide HTML you have in your page? I am afraid you are using wrong CSS selector in your jQuery code. For reason of this - you are facing  this problem.

Comment: hi @maksym i have it in my codepen http://codepen.io/mmahinay/pen/bBvdzw

Comment: Seems like you are using external plugin which inserts additional HTML onto the page. You need to find callback function in this plugin when it will be ready. Something like 'onInitialized' or something like this. When you find this callback - you will be able to make custom manipulations with DOM.

Answer (score 0):

> I needed to put my script after the body tag to make sure that my script runs after all the elements are loaded.

To ensure that all the elements are loaded before your script runs, you need to put your `<script>...</script>` at the end of the document body, just before `</body>`.

For a belt-and-braces approach do also use `$(document).ready();` like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
    [... HEAD CODE HERE...]
    </head>

    <body>
    [... BODY CODE HERE...]

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    [... JQUERY CODE HERE...]

    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you @rounin yes i am using the .ready() and have removed the .prepend() on the body

Answer (score 0):

Use the `eventAfterAllRender` event

```
     eventAfterAllRender:function(){

 //custom jquery
    if($('div.fc-bg table').length > 0 ){     

         var holiday = ['2016-12-01','2016-12-23','2016-12-30'];
            $.each(holiday, function(i, val){
                var date = val;//'2016-12-01';
                 $(".fc-day-top[data-date="+date+"]").addClass('holiday');        

            });     

    } //end of custom jquery


        }
```

demo:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObqVwy

Comment: thank you @madalinivascu i'm currently trying this one :)